# Test ssh connection as root

Tags: scripts, ssh, root

I'm trying to make an script just to test if I can connect throw ssh as root user in a list of servers that I have in a file, for the moment i have this:

```
for i in $(cat servers.list); do 
if [ "ssh root@$i" ] 
then  
echo "can connect as root in server $i" 
else 
echo "can't connect as root in server $i" 
fi 
done
```

But it always says that I can connect, even if it is not like this.

I would really appreciate some help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`[ "ssh root@$i" ]` tests whether the *string* `ssh root@$i` is non-empty - so of course it is always true.

Presumably what you want to do is quietly execute the command `ssh root@$i` and test its *exit status*:

```
if ssh -q root@$i; then
```

However, if this succeeds, it will (by default) open a login shell on `$i` - your loop will not continue until you have exited from such a shell. Perhaps it would be better to execute a specific command on the remote host:

```
if ssh -q root@$i /bin/true; then
```

Finally, looping over the result of a `cat` is a bad habit to get into: better to use a `while` loop:

```
while IFS= read -r i; do 
  if ssh -q root@"$i" /bin/true
  then  
    echo "can connect as root in server $i" 
  else 
    echo "can't connect as root in server $i" 
  fi 
done < servers.list
```

You might also want to take a look at `parallel-ssh` from the pssh package.